# Decompiler for PIC

Tags: pic, decompiler

I lost my code that I wrote for my PIC16F18346, so I had to read it from the PIC that I programmed before.
I have read a lot about the non-existence of a PIC decomiler (from assembly to C), but it's all a few years ago.
Does anybody know if one exists?
I know I will need to work afterwards because it's not perfect, but it's a big start.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about decompiling to assembler or decompiling to C?  Also, how much code are you talking about - tens, hundreds or thousands of bytes?  If it is tens or hundreds, you may be able to do it by hand.  MPLab will convert it to assembler for you.  You have to convert the assembler to C.

Comment: I'm looking for decompiler to C, I have it it assembly and it is 6000 lines.

Comment: I think you're out of luck there.

Comment: If you are willing to do manual work, a reverse engineering toolkit such as Ghidra may be helpful although its learning curve will be steep and properly reverse engineering your program will take lots of time. For the future, this is a good motivator toward having proper backups and version control.

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no perfect way to get back C code file using generated assembly file.